# Redrawing images on canvas using drawRect after fillRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning to make a simple game using canvas

http://codepen.io/mrbizle/pen/qZREjN

My game loop using requestAnimationFrame works as expected, until I try to fill the canvas with a color, and then immediately render a character. I then just get the background color.

```
   var render = function() {

        //canvasHelpers.setBg();    

        renderCharacters.player(); 
    };
```

Uncommenting canvasHelper.setBg demonstrates the problem.

Relevant functions:

```
var renderCharacter = function(x, y, bounce, size) {

    /**
     * The time since last draw time
    */
    var img = new Image();

    var svg = new Blob([characterSvgData], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
    });
    var url = domUrl.createObjectURL(svg);

    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y + bounce, size * 500, size * 250);
        domUrl.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }

    img.src = url;

};

...

setBg: function() {

    ctx.fillStyle = s.backgroundColor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because you are loading the image each render...

see my fork http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaKOBZ?editors=0010

declare the `Image`

```
var squirrelImage = new Image();
```

in init you can do

```
    var init = function() {

       ...

        var svg = new Blob([characterSvgData], {
            type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
        });
        var url = domUrl.createObjectURL(svg);
        squirrelImage.src = url;

       ...
    };
```

and do render

```
    var renderCharacter = function(x, y, bounce, size) {


              ctx.drawImage(squirrelImage, x, y + bounce, size * 500, size * 250);


    };
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh, Thanks for your time! Yep that was stupid of me. Will give it a whirl.